# Gaussian, which is run with nohup on remote linux machine, gets killed when the local computer is powered down before the shell is exited

Tags: shell, ssh, nohup

I have a problem running Gaussian on remote Linux via SecureCRT on Windows.

### Gaussian

[Gaussian](http://www.gaussian.com/g_prod/g09.htm) spawns different child executables [("link"s)](http://www.gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/m_linklist.htm) when running. For example, I start Gaussian by running `nohup g09 < test.in > test.out 2> test.out &`, and `g09` will spawns different `link`s such as `l301.exe` and `l502.exe` at specific circumstances.

### Run Gaussian

When I connect to the remote Linux box, and run Gaussian using `nohup ${Path_Of_Gaussian}/g09 < jobname.in > jobname.out 2> jobname.out &`:

1. If I exit the shell by typing `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I can exit
   while Gaussian on Linux keeps running (name of the specific executable depends on specific timing).
2. If I power down the computer (then the SecureCRT will be shutdown), Gaussian on Linux gets killed and complains "hang up".
3. If I exit by typing `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then log on, I can power down the computer and Gaussian on Linux keeps running.
4. `jlliagre`'s answer does not work in this case.

### Run simple command

Taken a simple executable, which does nothing (i.e., deals nothing with input & output) but sleeps for 10 minutes, for example. When I run it by `nohup ${Path_Of_Executable}/executable &`:

1. If I exit the shell by typing `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I can exit and the executable keeps running on Linux.
2. If I power down the computer (then the SecureCRT will be shutdown), the executable running on Linux gets killed.
3. If I exit by typing `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then log on, I can power down the computer (then the SecureCRT will be shutdown) and the executable on Linux keeps running.
4. As in `jlliagre`'s knowledgeable answer, if I run `nohup ${Path_Of_Executable}/executable </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`, I can power down while the executable on Linux keeps running.

In other words, why would Gaussian, which is run on a remote machine with `nohup`, get killed when the local computer is powered down before the shell is exited?

Comment: What do you do with STDIN/STDOUT for the apps?  Might want to try [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) so the app always has a "terminal".

Comment: What about redirecting stderr, that is now stdout to /dev/null.

Comment: What shell and system are you using?

Comment: to help isolate this, install putty [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html] on windows and see if you get the same behavior. If you do, We need to troubleshoot the linux box. If The behavior is different you need to find out what secureCRT sends when you kill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Idea #1 - disown

Based on the way you're describing your problem it sounds like Guassian still has some linkages to the shell that it was spawned from.

One additional thing you could try in addition to the `nohup` is to run `disown -a` as well, though this should do the same thing of disconnecting all the spawned processes from receiving SIGHUP.

#### Idea #2 - wrap it inside another Bash

Another thought would be to invoke Guassian like this.

1. login to remote machine
2. nohup bash
3. run Guassian in this secondary shell

This might insulate Guassian from being terminated when the local machine loses the connection.

#### Idea #3 - use tmux or screen

I've run into applications similar to this as well, and rather than bang my head on the desk too much, I usually just reach for `screen` and/or `tmux` and run the application on the remote system inside Screen.

This protects the process better and has the added benefit of being able to reconnect with it later on.

Comment: Thank you very much! The `disown -a` after the `nohup` command has helped !

Comment: Thank you for the help... 8.5 years later!

Answer (score 2):

This should better detach your application:

```
nohup ${PATH_OF_APPLICATION}/app </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If this still doesn't work for some reason, try:

```
echo ${PATH_OF_APPLICATION}/app | at now
```

Comment: @jilliagre: Thanks! Sorry that I just tried and still gets killed and complaints about hang up. Could you help to comment ?

Comment: @XichenLi That should not happen, especially with the `at` method. At this point I'd attach an strace to the program and see what's going on.

Comment: @Patrick I added the `at` suggestion after Xichen Li comment.

Comment: @jilliagre: Thanks! The `at` does not get the executable running at all. Do I need high privilege? I am a normal non-root.

Comment: @XichenLi at may not be installed standard apt-get or yum will probably install it for you.

Comment: @XichenLi can you provide more details about what happens when you try the `at` command ?